# Dynamic Company Name on PDF

Tags: docusignapi

I have a place on my pdf that says, I authorize .....
I would like to dynamicly put in the Company Name here that will be use in the same template

is there a way like how I pass recipientName, I can also pass company Name so that it can display here.

Comment: Please show some research effort, also more details about what technology are you using.

Comment: What Yahya said. Regardless, if you try to modify characters in a PDF be prepared to enter a world of pain. Maybe you can archive what you want without replacing content in a pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Please research the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/devcenter), as it answers this question and many more you may have.  If you look at the `Explore` -> `Features` section you'll see in the *Stick-eTabs* section an area that describes **Tab Positioning**.  Here it explains the two main ways of placing tabs on your documents.

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs

The Tab Positioning in the above page describes how you can place tags using `Absolute` positioning (i.e. 100 pixels to the left, 50 pixels down), or you can use `Relative` (aka Anchor) positioning.  With anchor tabs you can place tabs based on document content.  For your example of placing a company tab at or near the text "I authorize...", you can use the following (partial) JSON:

```
"tabs": {
    "companyTabs": [
        {
            "anchorString": "I authorize...",
            "anchorXOffset": "1",
            "anchorYOffset": "0",
            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
            "anchorUnits": "inches"
        }
    ]
}
```

This would in turn place a `companyName` tab 1-inch to the right of the text "I authorize..." in your document.  You can place any DocuSign tab using the Anchor Tagging method, but one thing to note is that it will place those tags at ANY and EVERY location it finds the `anchorString` text in the envelope.